# Microsoft.Speech general language grammar

Tags: .net, speech-recognition

If we use an integrated Windows 7 feature of speech recognition, we can see, that it is pretty good at guessing what we have dictated. And it works not only with a limited set of commands, but with any spoken word.

On the other hand, when I try to program against classes in Microsoft.Speech namespace (Microsoft Speech Server Runtime 10.2 is what I have installed), I find myself in need of always defining a limited grammar to use.

Is there a way to just get a dictated audio file and try to parse it to text, without specifying a custom grammar in Microsoft.Speech?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the desktop operating systems come with a dictation grammar. However, the server recognizers do not include a dictation grammar because they were primarily intended for telephony use where users give short commands to an IVR system. For some more background, this question may be helpful - [What is the best option for transcribing speech-to-text in a asp.net web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730318/what-is-the-best-option-for-transcribing-speech-to-text-in-a-asp-net-web-app/4737003#4737003)

Remember that the desktop recognizers are used by a single user at a time. They can be trained to improve recognition for each user. Server recognizers are designed to handle many users simultaneously. Server recognizers cannot be trained. Perhaps, an accurate dictation grammar is too difficult without training? (Or, perhaps Microsoft doesn't want to give away all of their best technology?)

I've also read (but haven't checked) that the desktop recognizers support higher quality audio (higher bit rate and sample size) and the server recognizers are limited to telephony quality audio. Perhaps accurate transcription requires the higher quality audio.

Comment: You may be right. Still why not to make a dictation grammar for server recognizer, making it even more functional.

Comment: An example in the referenced question is great. Thank you.